# How to specify a literal field name in a LINQ Query where clause?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

The following 2 methods are part of a generic Repository Pattern implementation.

GetById works and returns the row with Id == id.

GetByIdIncludingEntities has the problem.  It needs to work similarly to GetById with the additional feature of including (loading) related entity rows specified in the “entities” array.  Currently it works but it returns the first row in a multi-row result.  It needs to only return the row that has Id == id.  Note all entities have a primary key named “Id” which are an integers (see entity model below).

```
public virtual TEntity GetByIdIncludingEntities(int id, string[] entities)
{
    // id: The primary key value to find.
    // entities: Array of related entities to eagerly load.  i.e., “BigThings”

    var query = from q in context.Set<TEntity>() select q;

    foreach (string entity in entities)
    {
        query = query.Include(entity);
    }

    return query.SingleOrDefault();
}

public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
{
    return context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
}

Here is a sample entity for reference.

[Table("Things")]
public class Thing
{
    public Thing()
    {
        this.BigThings = new HashSet<BigThing>();
        this.SmallThings = new HashSet<SmallThing>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<BigThing> BigThings { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<SmallThing> SmallThings { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you want to Find by Id... don't use

```
return query.SingleOrDefault();
```

(which will probably raise an exception, by the way)

use

```
return query.Find(id);
```

By the way, to avoid strings, you could use

```
public virtual TEntity GetByIdIncludingEntities(int id, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> []  entities)
{
  var query = context.Set<TEntity>();
  foreach (var entity in entities)
      query = query.Include(entity);

  return query.Find(id;
}
```

as there's an overload for Include which takes an `Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>>` as parameter (you may have to import the correct namespace to get it).

then usage would be

```
repository.GetByIdIncludingEntities<Entity1>(id, m => m.RelatedEntity, m=> m.OtherRelatedEntity)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like this is going to work.  Marking as answer.  Everything compiled after force fitting it into my web service, but received and error.

Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.